# Duplicate contours in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hierarchy, gpuimage

I am having a some trouble with findContours in opencv. There is too much data in the output and I know that properly using the hierarchy is the key. Given the image below from the opencv docs:

[image: Opencv Docs]

I would like to draw all the contours except for 2a and 3a. What is the proper way to traverse the hierarchy and findContour arguments to achieve that result?

Comment: Can you share the original image?

Comment: Isn't there a black image above with white lines and red numbers? If not, the original image can be found at the top of the page [HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html)

Comment: I thought the red numbers were something you added on purpose to illustrate which contours you were trying to detect.

Comment: In the same tutorial, read about flag : `RETR_CCOMP`. I hope it will get you a two-level hierarchy in which 2a and 3a belongs to level 2 while all others are level 1. (I haven't tried so I can tell for sure. Check it yourself)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contours found by findContours function has direction. Objects are counter clockwise, and holes are clockwise. So if you check signed area of each contour, you will know whether this is a hole or not by its sign. Signed area of contour can be calculated in following way:

```
contourArea(contour, true);
```

Of course using hierarchy is a good approach as well but I think this approach is simpler to understand and implement.

Comment: For my needs this is clean and works at about 85% accuracy. I tried adding skeletonization (as suggested above) to the mix but the output was too minimal. I have a few double lines but nothing like before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Michael Burdinov said, returns +ve and -ve values for objects or holdes